# Disable Callchooser in Linphone

Tags: android, linphone

I customized the Linphone open source project and created my own app. Everything is working fine. Only issue is

**When the user dials a number it asks the user to select the dialer as shown in the picture. [image]
.**

I dont want my app to be listed here as I dont want the users to make SIP calls using my app(I want my app to allow calls only to the other users of my app).

Answer (score 0):

you can remove this type of code from your android menifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
```

Hope it may help you.

Comment: I dont have it in manifest. But all activities in the app have this Intent filter:<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: And I guess it's not for that purpose.